# Getting a wrong result while computing the cross product of unit vectors $\hat{i}$ and $\hat{j}$

Tags: vectors, coordinate-systems, cross-product

Consider the coordinate system as shown below and unit vectors along x and y, $\hat{i}$ and $\hat{j}$. The cross product of these unit vectors as given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#:%7E:text=%5Bedit%5D-,Coordinate%20notation,-%5Bedit%5D) is equal to $\hat{k}$. However, when I apply the right-hand rule, point my 4 fingers in the direction of $\hat{i}$ and curl them in the direction of $\hat{j}$ I get my thumb pointing towards $\hat{-k}$.

[image]

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You've mirrored your picture and so you should use the mirrored (left-hand) rule. Or just draw the mirror image of what you have already drawn. The equality $i\times j=k$ is valid at all times, but "right-hand rule" or "left-hand rule" is a convention that stems from the way we draw things. (In fact, the last sentence should be obvious: math should not depend on the appendages of the certain creatures who purport to understand it.)

Comment: This is a left-hand coordinate system

Comment: Oh. Thank you, Bishop and Ronny. I had no idea about right-handed and left-handed coordinate systems. Learned something new and important today. So, a right-handed coordinate system is the one in which when I point my right hand fingers along x axis and curl them along y, I get my thumb pointing towards z. Since, this is not the case here, this represents a left handed coordinate system, in which left hand thumb rule will apply. A left hand coordinate system will be the one in which when I direct my left hand fingers along x, and curl them along y, I get my left thumb pointing  z. Right?

Answer (score 2):

I think that you drew the orientation of the diagram wrong.